# how to loop over the videos and write the information in sepreate folders?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a main folder which has multiple folders, including input with multiple sub-folders each sub-folder has a video in it. I loop over input (its sub-folders) and process them. I wish to write the processed information into the output file. Currently everything is written in only one output folder. But I would like to have an output folder like this where I can have multiple sub folders to write processed info related to each video.

**What I am currently doing:**

```
mainfolder
    ├── input
    │   │   
    │   ├── sub-folder1/ video1.mp4
    │   ├── sub-folder2/ video2.mp4
    │   └── sub-folder3/ video3.mp4
    |
    ├── output/ everything get over written here
    │  
    │
    │
    ├── main_code.py
```

**What I wish to do:**

```
mainfolder
├── input
│   │   
│   ├── sub-folder1/ video1.mp4
│   ├── sub-folder2/ video2.mp4
│   └── sub-folder3/ video3.mp4
├── output
│   ├── sub-folder1/ processed-info(video1)
│   ├── sub-folder2/ processed-info(video2)
│   └── sub-folder3/ processed-info(video3)
│
│
├── main_code.py
```

After doing some process for each video under sub-folder, I want to write frames into the same locations as of each sub-folder.

Here is the loop over sub-folders, each has a video in it:

```
 mainFolder= 'input'
myFolders= os.listdir(mainFolder)

for folder in myFolders:
    path=mainFolder+ '/'+ folder
    print(path)
    vidoes=[]
    myList=os.listdir(path)

    for vidN in myList:
        vs=cv2.VideoCapture(f'{path}/{vidN}')
        vidoes.append(vs)
```

After processing each video, I write the out put of the frames, .txt file and processed video into an output folder. This causes an overwriting issue. How do I create folders with the same name as the videos inside the output folder to prevent overwriting?

```
directory_name1 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'output','frames1')
                        if not os.path.exists(directory_name1):
                            os.makedirs(directory_name1)

                        frame_path1= os.path.join(directory_name1,f"frame1-{frameIndex}.png")
                        cv2.imwrite(frame_path1,frame)



output_string=f"{ID}, {count} \n"
                            print(output_string)
                            with open(outputFilename, 'a') as file_writer:
                                file_writer.write(output_string)




# check if the video writer is None
        if writer is None:
            # initialize our video writer
            fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")

            directory_out= 'output'

            if not os.path.exists(directory_out):
                os.makedirs(directory_out)

            writer = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join(directory_out,'out.avi'), fourcc, 120,
                                     (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)
```

I can loop over video files, but when I try to write the output it overwrites. My question is how do I direct output for each videos into a separate sub folder?

Comment: could you give a minimal example of what your directory and file structures look like now and what you'd like them to look like?

Comment: Hi, I added those, is that clear now?

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding - you wish to put your output files (including the video that was processed) into a newly created folder that has the same name as the video inside it. Creating this new folder in your desired location overwrites an existing folder with that same name in that desired location, and you want to avoid that?

Comment: Would it work for you to prefix the of the new file, for example with proc_ (for processed)? That would avoid overwriting and creating directories for one file each time.

Comment: @Kendle's idea would work. OP, you may also consider having a process that creates a new directory to contain all the new subfolders for each time you run that file. This would avoid name clashing altogether without having to prefix new files/folders except for the new directory.

Comment: I edited my post to explain the issue in more details. @Kendle, could you please explain your idea with an example, sorry I could not understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little program to demonstrate modifying the filename.We have to double escape the . as separateur.Of course you could seperate on "/" or "" depending on the OS and reconstruct the filename with a new subfolder, that you would have to create.It could be done but would be much more complicated.

```
class FileName {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String fileName = "/path/to/my/file/video.mp4";
                String[] parts = fileName.split("\\.");
                String newFileName = parts[0] + ".proc." + parts[1];
                System.out.println(newFileName);
                }
}
```